# How to change price in Pricing table on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to create price changing button that working like this,

LINK: https://www.teamgate.com/pricing/

if, there have any java script or anything please give me solution
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: I check many example from internet but its not working same like this. and my client want same like this.

Comment: at least write a code and we will help you in some part you don't know..

Comment: Which framework are you use? Or vanille JS?

Comment: With pure JS you have to add a listener on € $ and which modify the innerHTML of the prices. You have to create also 3 object on each currency, and get them in the target div.

Comment: yes, i just make like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zFFEe/ but i want to change three value at one click

Comment: Just add 2 more price after each UL LI:
Like:
       `                     <ul class="gallery" id="yellowGallery">`
        `                        <li>£20</li>`
         `                       <li>£23</li>`
          `                      <li>£24</li>`
                                
           `                 </ul>`

Comment: yes, you are right boss, but i want that <li>20</li> in different <div> so its not working there

Comment: given a simple answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown anything what you have attempted, this can be done in many ways. Just showing a small snippet which i created, the rest of the research & coding is up to you.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $('.hash').click(function() {
    $('.price').html("€8.39");
    $('.price2').html("€10.06");
  });
});

jQuery(function() {
  $('.percent').click(function() {
    $('.price').html("£7.45");
    $('.price2').html("£8.93");
  });
});
```

```css
div.price {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.price2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">$10</div>
<div class="price2">$12</div>
<button class="hash">Euro</button>
<button class="percent">Pound</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not having a piece of your code, I can't write a proper solution, but looking at the example that you've given I would recommend using the HTML DOM innerHTML Property. I'll leave here a link to the documentation, where is perfectly explained. [LINK TO DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

With innerHTML you will be able to change dinamically the content of specific elements whenever you want. Hope this helps you!

I've coded a little snipet. Tell me if that's what you want (with tables or divs).

```js
function doFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="doFunction();" />
<p id="demo">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>
</body>
</html>
```